# Fitting 4 Tables into One Page

Tags: tables, spacing, floats, horizontal-alignment

When I want to include 4 tables in one specific page only 3 can be included but the fourth just keeps going to a new page. How can I adjust the float so that all fit within one page?

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\usepackage{import}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{footnote}

\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}

\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}%

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{multicols}{2}

%20 Degrees
%\begin{table}[]
%\centering
%\caption{My caption}
%\label{my-label}
\resizebox{7cm}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{\textbf{Temperature: 20 ±0.01 °C}}                                   \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Volume of CO$_2$} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}    \\ \hline
Repetition             & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & Control=0g/20s           \\ \hline
Time (±0.5 s.)         &       &       &       &       &       & Volume of HCl (±0.2 ml)    \\ \hline
0                      & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
5                      & 0     & 1.5   & 1     & 0     & 0     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
10                     & 0     & 2     & 1.5   & 0.5   & 1     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
15                     & 0     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 2     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
20                     & 2     & 2.5   & 2.5   & 2     & 2.5   & \Huge{\color{orange}{1}} \\ \cline{1-6}
25                     & 3     & 3     & 2.5   & 3     & 3     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
30                     & 3.5   & 3     & 3     & 3.5   & 3.5   &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
35                     & 4     & 3     & 3     & 4     & 4     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
40                     & 4     & 3     & 3     & 4     & 4     &                          \\ \hline
0                      & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
5                      & 0.5   & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
10                     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0.5   & 1     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
15                     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
20                     & 4     & 4     & 3.5   & 3.5   & 3.5   & \Huge{\color{gray}{2}}   \\ \cline{1-6}
25                     & 6     & 5     & 5     & 5     & 4     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
30                     & 7     & 5.5   & 6     & 6     & 6     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
35                     & 7.5   & 6     & 6.5   & 7.5   & 8     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
40                     & 7.5   & 6     & 7     & 7.5   & 9     &                          \\ \hline
0                      & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
5                      & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
10                     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
15                     & 3     & 3     & 2     & 3     & 4     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
20                     & 4     & 4     & 5     & 4     & 5     & \Huge{\color{blue}{3}}   \\ \cline{1-6}
25                     & 5     & 6     & 6     & 6     & 7     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
30                     & 7     & 8.5   & 7.5   & 7.5   & 10    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
35                     & 8     & 11    & 10    & 10    & 12    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
40                     & 9     & 12    & 12    & 12.5  & 13.5  &                          \\ \hline
0                      & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
5                      & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
10                     & 2     & 3     & 2     & 3     & 1     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
15                     & 5     & 6     & 3     & 4.5   & 3     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
20                     & 4     & 9     & 4.5   & 6.5   & 5     & \Huge{\color{red}{4}}    \\ \cline{1-6}
25                     & 8     & 11    & 8.5   & 8     & 8.5   &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
30                     & 12    & 13    & 10    & 10.5  & 10    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
35                     & 14    & 16    & 12.5  & 12.5  & 13.5  &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
40                     & 15    & 17    & 15    & 15.5  & 15    &                          \\ \hline
0                      & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
5                      & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
10                     & 4     & 3     & 3     & 2     & 3     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
15                     & 6     & 4,5   & 4.5   & 3.5   & 5     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
20                     & 8.5   & 8     & 7     & 8     & 8     & \Huge{\color{green}{5}}  \\ \cline{1-6}
25                     & 12    & 11    & 11    & 11    & 10.5  &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
30                     & 14.5  & 14.5  & 14    & 14    & 14    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
35                     & 17.5  & 17    & 17    & 17    & 17.5  &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
40                     & 19    & 20    & 20    & 20    & 20    &                          \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
%\end{table}



%25 Degrees%
%\begin{table}[]
%\centering
%\caption{My caption}
%\label{my-label}
\resizebox{7cm}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{\textbf{Temperature: 25 ±0.01 °C}}                                   \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Volume of CO$_2$} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}    \\ \hline
Repetition             & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & Control = 0g/20s         \\ \hline
Time (±0.5 s.)         &       &       &       &       &       & Volume of HCl (±0.2 ml)  \\ \hline
0                      & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
5                      & 2     & 2     & 1.5   & 2     & 1.5   &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
10                     & 4     & 3.5   & 3     & 3     & 3     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
15                     & 5     & 5     & 4.5   & 4     & 4     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
20                     & 6     & 6     & 5     & 4.5   & 4.5   & \Huge{\color{orange}{1}} \\ \cline{1-6}
25                     & 8     & 8.5   & 6.5   & 5     & 5     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
30                     & 8.5   & 9     & 8     & 6     & 6.5   &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
35                     & 9     & 9.5   & 9.5   & 8     & 8.5   &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
40                     & 9     & 9.5   & 9.5   & 8.5   & 9.5   &                          \\ \hline
0                      & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
5                      & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
10                     & 3     & 4     & 3.5   & 4     & 4     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
15                     & 3.5   & 6     & 5     & 6     & 6     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
20                     & 5     & 8     & 7     & 8     & 9     & \Huge{\color{gray}{2}}   \\ \cline{1-6}
25                     & 6.5   & 9     & 8.5   & 9.5   & 9.5   &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
30                     & 9     & 11    & 10    & 11    & 11    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
35                     & 10    & 12.5  & 12.5  & 13    & 12.5  &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
40                     & 11    & 14.5  & 14    & 14    & 14.5  &                          \\ \hline
0                      & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
5                      & 3     & 3     & 3     & 3     & 3     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
10                     & 5     & 6     & 6     & 6     & 6     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
15                     & 8     & 9     & 9     & 9     & 8     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
20                     & 10    & 13    & 13    & 13    & 11    & \Huge{\color{blue}{3}}   \\ \cline{1-6}
25                     & 12.5  & 16    & 16    & 14.5  & 14    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
30                     & 15.5  & 18    & 18    & 17    & 16    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
35                     & 19    & 20    & 20    & 19    & 19    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
40                     & 21    & 21    & 21    & 20    & 22    &                          \\ \hline
0                      & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
5                      & 4     & 3     & 3     & 3     & 3     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
10                     & 6     & 6     & 6     & 6     & 6     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
15                     & 8     & 10    & 8     & 8.5   & 8     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
20                     & 10    & 14    & 12    & 11.5  & 10    & \Huge{\color{red}{4}}    \\ \cline{1-6}
25                     & 14    & 18    & 15    & 15    & 14    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
30                     & 18    & 22    & 18.5  & 18    & 18    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
35                     & 21    & 25    & 21    & 21    & 20    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
40                     & 24    & 27    & 24    & 23.5  & 22    &                          \\ \hline
0                      & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
5                      & 3     & 3     & 3     & 3     & 3     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
10                     & 6     & 6     & 6     & 6     & 6.5   &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
15                     & 8     & 10    & 10    & 10    & 8     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
20                     & 12    & 14    & 14    & 15    & 12    & \Huge{\color{green}{5}}  \\ \cline{1-6}
25                     & 16    & 18    & 18    & 20    & 16    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
30                     & 20    & 20    & 22    & 25    & 20    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
35                     & 23    & 23    & 26    & 27    & 24    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
40                     & 25    & 25    & 28    & 29    & 28    &                          \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
%\end{table}


\end{multicols}

\begin{multicols}{2}

%30 Degrees%
\resizebox{7cm}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{\textbf{Temperature: 30 ±0.01 °C}}                                   \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Volume of CO$_2$} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}    \\ \hline
Repetition             & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & Control = 0g/20s         \\ \hline
Time (±0.5 s.)         &       &       &       &       &       & Volume of HCl (±0.2 ml)  \\ \hline
0                      & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
5                      & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 3     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
10                     & 3     & 3     & 3     & 3     & 5     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
15                     & 5     & 5     & 5     & 5     & 7     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
20                     & 7     & 7.5   & 7     & 8     & 9     & \Huge{\color{orange}{1}} \\ \cline{1-6}
25                     & 9     & 10    & 9     & 11    & 11    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
30                     & 11    & 11    & 10    & 12    & 12    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
35                     & 12    & 12    & 12    & 12.5  & 12.5  &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
40                     & 12.5  & 13    & 12.5  & 13    & 13    &                          \\ \hline
0                      & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
5                      & 3.5   & 3     & 3     & 3     & 3     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
10                     & 5     & 5     & 7     & 5     & 4     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
15                     & 7     & 9     & 10    & 8     & 9     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
20                     & 11    & 12    & 14    & 12    & 12    & \Huge{\color{gray}{2}}   \\ \cline{1-6}
25                     & 13    & 15    & 16    & 15    & 16    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
30                     & 15    & 18    & 18    & 18    & 18    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
35                     & 17    & 20    & 20    & 20    & 20.5  &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
40                     & 17.5  & 21    & 22    & 22    & 24    &                          \\ \hline
0                      & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
5                      & 4     & 3     & 3     & 3     & 3     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
10                     & 7.5   & 8     & 6     & 6     & 6     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
15                     & 13.5  & 12    & 10    & 10    & 10    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
20                     & 14    & 15    & 13    & 13    & 12    & \Huge{\color{blue}{3}}   \\ \cline{1-6}
25                     & 18    & 18    & 16    & 16.5  & 14    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
30                     & 20.5  & 22    & 20    & 20    & 18    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
35                     & 24    & 26    & 23.5  & 23    & 23    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
40                     & 26.5  & 28    & 26    & 26    & 25    &                          \\ \hline
0                      & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
5                      & 2     & 3     & 3     & 3     & 3     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
10                     & 6     & 6     & 7     & 6     & 6     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
15                     & 10    & 10    & 10    & 10    & 10    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
20                     & 14    & 15    & 14.5  & 14    & 14    & \Huge{\color{red}{4}}    \\ \cline{1-6}
25                     & 16    & 19.5  & 18    & 19    & 20    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
30                     & 20    & 24.5  & 24    & 23    & 25    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
35                     & 24    & 28    & 28    & 26    & 28    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
40                     & 28.5  & 32    & 32    & 30    & 30    &                          \\ \hline
0                      & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
5                      & 3     & 3     & 3     & 3     & 3     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
10                     & 7     & 10    & 10    & 10    & 10    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
15                     & 11    & 15    & 14    & 15    & 15    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
20                     & 16    & 20    & 19    & 20    & 20    & \Huge{\color{green}{5}}  \\ \cline{1-6}
25                     & 20    & 25    & 25    & 26    & 25    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
30                     & 25    & 30    & 30    & 32    & 32    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
35                     & 30    & 36    & 35    & 37    & 40    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
40                     & 35    & 42    & 40    & 40    & 44    &                          \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
%\end{table}


%35 Degrees%
%\begin{table}[]
%\centering
%\caption{My caption}
%\label{my-label}
\resizebox{7cm}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{\textbf{Temperature: 35 ±0.01 °C}}                                   \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Volume of CO$_2$} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}    \\ \hline
Repetition             & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & Control = 0g/20s         \\ \hline
Time (±0.5 s.)         &       &       &       &       &       & Volume of HCl (±0.2 ml)  \\ \hline
0                      & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
5                      & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
10                     & 3     & 4     & 3     & 3     & 3     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
15                     & 5     & 5     & 5     & 5     & 6     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
20                     & 7.5   & 7     & 8     & 8     & 8     & \Huge{\color{orange}{1}} \\ \cline{1-6}
25                     & 10    & 10    & 10    & 10    & 10    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
30                     & 12    & 13    & 12    & 12    & 12    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
35                     & 14    & 14    & 14    & 13.5  & 14    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
40                     & 15    & 14.5  & 15    & 14.5  & 15    &                          \\ \hline
0                      & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
5                      & 3     & 3     & 3     & 3     & 3     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
10                     & 6     & 5     & 5     & 6     & 5     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
15                     & 10    & 8     & 7     & 10    & 10    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
20                     & 13    & 12    & 10    & 14    & 13    & \Huge{\color{gray}{2}}   \\ \cline{1-6}
25                     & 15    & 15    & 13    & 17    & 17    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
30                     & 18    & 17    & 15    & 20    & 20    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
35                     & 20    & 19    & 17    & 22    & 22    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
40                     & 21    & 20    & 19    & 24    & 23.5  &                          \\ \hline
0                      & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
5                      & 4     & 4     & 4     & 4     & 4     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
10                     & 8     & 7     & 8     & 7.5   & 8     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
15                     & 13    & 12    & 12    & 11.5  & 13    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
20                     & 18    & 17    & 15    & 15    & 15    & \Huge{\color{blue}{3}}   \\ \cline{1-6}
25                     & 24    & 22    & 19    & 20    & 19    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
30                     & 26    & 27.5  & 24    & 24    & 22    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
35                     & 29    & 30.5  & 27    & 27    & 25    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
40                     & 33    & 32    & 30    & 29.5  & 29    &                          \\ \hline
0                      & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
5                      & 4     & 3     & 4     & 4     & 4     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
10                     & 9     & 8     & 10    & 10    & 10    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
15                     & 15    & 15    & 15    & 15    & 16    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
20                     & 19    & 20    & 20    & 20    & 21    & \Huge{\color{red}{4}}    \\ \cline{1-6}
25                     & 24    & 23    & 24.5  & 25    & 26    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
30                     & 29    & 26    & 29    & 30.5  & 32    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
35                     & 33.5  & 28    & 33    & 33    & 37    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
40                     & 35    & 30    & 36    & 35    & 39    &                          \\ \hline
0                      & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
5                      & 3     & 3     & 3.5   & 3     & 3     &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
10                     & 10    & 10    & 12    & 10    & 13    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
15                     & 17    & 18    & 20    & 17    & 20    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
20                     & 25    & 25    & 26    & 24    & 27    & \Huge{\color{green}{5}}  \\ \cline{1-6}
25                     & 30.5  & 30    & 32    & 32    & 33    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
30                     & 34    & 34    & 38    & 40    & 38    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
35                     & 38    & 37    & 42    & 45    & 44    &                          \\ \cline{1-6}
40                     & 42    & 40    & 45    & 50    & 50    &                          \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
%\end{table}

\end{multicols}

\end {document}
```

[image]

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It seems that your tables are to big to be placed on one page ...

Comment: also your `\Huge` coloured figures are messing up ypur line spacing (and making the tables even bigger (use `\smash{\Huge{\textcolor{red}{2}}}` to hide the height)

Comment: @ David Carlisle Nice Spotting! Thank you so much it actually helped me ge the required space. I had been spending so much time on this haha. Thank you again!

Comment: @user128290, any news?

Answer (score 1):

In name of all who will ones read your table(s), don't squeeze them to unreadable small size!

Your tables, regardless that you use `\resizebox{...}` are to big (tall) that they can be put in one page. To resolve this problem, you have few possibilities:

- consider to redesign them in another form,
- see my comments on the end of this answer.

Regarding first option, I suggest you to merge these four tables in one table, where you drop repeating columns (first, last) and reorganize column headers.

Beside aforementioned, please consider :

- Better looking of table can be obtain with use of rules from `booktabs` package, omitting vertical lines and align all numbers at decimal points, for example with use `S` columns from package `siunitx`.
- Use standardized writing of units and tolerances. This can be simple done by use of package `siunitx`.
- Use `multicols` for placement of tables, is not very fruitfully approach.

Yes, all suggested changes require quite off work, but (to my opinion) it is worth of effort. Imagination, how will look result, can be estimated from following image of table:

[image]

As you see, in table I enlarge numbers of the end. Their purpose from table is not clear, so I make them (fore fun) far bigger then are with use of `\huge` font size :) . Also I header of this column into first row.

A my MWE I comment all packages from your, which is not related to table. Also I slightly reorganize preamble: delete packages, which are called by others (`mathtools` call `amsmathm`, `pgfplots` call `tikz`, `xcolor` is extension of `color` and can also call `colortbl`, ...) and add some packages, which I use in table (`booktabs`, `makecell` and `msiunitx`) and define two new commands for simplify table writing.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
%\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{chemfig}
%\usepackage{import}
%\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usepackage{footnote}
%\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}

\usepackage[showframe,% to show page layout
            margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% it sufficient for all where you like to use colors
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{booktabs, longtable, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{5}{c}{#1}}
\newcommand\case[2]{\multirowcell{9}{
    \fontsize{44}{44}\bfseries\color{#1}\selectfont #2}
                                    }

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[]\footnotesize\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
%20 Degrees
    \centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
    \begin{tabular}{S[table-format=2.0]
              *{20}{S[table-format=2.1]}
                    c
                    }
    \toprule
\multicolumn{21}{c}{Volume of CO$_2$;\qquad *: $\text{Control}= \SI{0}{g}/\SI{2}{0}{s}$ /
                     Volume of HCl (\SI{\pm 0.2}{ml}}                           \\
    \midrule
    &   \mc{\SI[separate-uncertainty]{20.00(01)}{\degreeCelsius}}   
        &   \mc{\SI[separate-uncertainty]{25.00(01)}{\degreeCelsius}}
            &   \mc{\SI[separate-uncertainty]{30.00(01)}{\degreeCelsius}}
                &   \mc{\SI[separate-uncertainty]{35.00(01)}{\degreeCelsius}} 
                    &                                                           \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-6}  \cmidrule(lr){7-11} \cmidrule(lr){12-16}    \cmidrule(lr){17-21}
{Repetit.}      & 1    & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     
                & 1    & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5
                    & 1    & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5
                        & 1    & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5    & *           \\
    \midrule 
{\makecell{Time\\ (±0.5 s.)}}  &&&&& &&&&& &&&&& &&&&&                      \\
    \midrule
0           & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     
                & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0
                    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0
                        & 0    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     &
                                                        \case{orange}{1}    \\              
5           & 0     & 1.5   & 1     & 0     & 0     
                & 2     & 2     & 1.5   & 2     & 1.5 
                    & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 3     
                        & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2  &               \\
10          & 0     & 2     & 1.5   & 0.5   & 1     
                & 4     & 3.5   & 3     & 3     & 3     
                    & 3     & 3     & 3     & 3     & 5 
                        & 3     & 4     & 3     & 3     & 3                  \\
15          & 0     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 2
                & 5     & 5     & 4.5   & 4     & 4   
                    & 5     & 5     & 5     & 5     & 7     
                        & 3     & 4     & 3     & 3     & 3 \\

20          & 2     & 2.5   & 2.5   & 2     & 2.5   
                & 6     & 6     & 5     & 4.5   & 4.5
                    & 7     & 7.5   & 7     & 8     & 9
                        & 7.5   & 7     & 8     & 8     & 8      &          \\
25          & 3    & 3     & 2.5   & 3     & 3     
                & 8     & 8.5   & 6.5   & 5     & 5
                    & 9     & 10    & 9     & 11    & 11
                        & 10    & 10    & 10    & 10    & 10    &           \\   
30          & 3.5   & 3     & 3     & 3.5   & 3.5
                & 8.5   & 9     & 8     & 6     & 6.5
                    & 11    & 11    & 10    & 12    & 12
                        & 12    & 13    & 12    & 12    & 12    &           \\
35          & 4    & 3     & 3     & 4     & 4
                & 9     & 9.5   & 9.5   & 8     & 8.5  
                    & 12    & 12    & 12    & 12.5  & 12.5
                        & 14    & 14    & 14    & 13.5  & 14    &           \\
40          & 4     & 3     & 3     & 4     & 4     
                & 9     & 9.5   & 9.5   & 8.5   & 9.5
                    & 12.5  & 13    & 12.5  & 13    & 13
                        & 15    & 14.5  & 15    & 14.5  & 15    &           \\ 
    \midrule
0           & 0    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0
                & 0    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0
                   & 0    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0
                       & 0    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     &
                                                        \case{gray}{2}   \\
5           & 0.5  & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     \\
10          & 1    & 0     & 0     & 0.5   & 1     \\
15          & 2    & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     \\
20          & 4    & 4     & 3.5   & 3.5   & 3.5   \\
25          & 6    & 5     & 5     & 5     & 4     \\
30          & 7    & 5.5   & 6     & 6     & 6     \\
35          & 7.5  & 6     & 6.5   & 7.5   & 8     \\
40          & 7.5  & 6     & 7     & 7.5   & 9     \\
    \midrule
0           & 0    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0
                & 0    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0
                   & 0    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0
                       & 0    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     &
                                                        \case{blue}{3}   \\
5           & 0    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1     \\
10          & 2    & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     \\
15          & 3    & 3     & 2     & 3     & 4     \\
20          & 4    & 4     & 5     & 4     & 5     \\
25          & 5    & 6     & 6     & 6     & 7     \\
30          & 7    & 8.5   & 7.5   & 7.5   & 10    \\
35          & 8    & 11    & 10    & 10    & 12    \\
40          & 9    & 12    & 12    & 12.5  & 13.5  \\ 
    \midrule
0           & 0    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0
                & 0    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0
                   & 0    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0
                       & 0    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     &
                                                        \case{red}{4}   \\
5           & 0    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     \\
10          & 2    & 3     & 2     & 3     & 1     \\
15          & 5    & 6     & 3     & 4.5   & 3     \\
20          & 4    & 9     & 4.5   & 6.5   & 5     \\
25          & 8    & 11    & 8.5   & 8     & 8.5   \\
30          & 12   & 13    & 10    & 10.5  & 10    \\
35          & 14   & 16    & 12.5  & 12.5  & 13.5  \\
40          & 15   & 17    & 15    & 15.5  & 15    \\ 
    \midrule
0           & 0    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0
                & 0    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0
                   & 0    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0
                       & 0    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     &
                                                        \case{green}{5}  \\
5           & 0    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     \\
10          & 4    & 3     & 3     & 2     & 3     \\
15          & 6    & 4,5   & 4.5   & 3.5   & 5     \\
20          & 8.5  & 8     & 7     & 8     & 8     \\
25          & 12   & 11    & 11    & 11    & 10.5  \\
30          & 14.5 & 14.5  & 14    & 14    & 14    \\
35          & 17.5 & 17    & 17    & 17    & 17.5  \\
40          & 19   & 20    & 20    & 20    & 20    \\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end {document}
```

I you will not like above solution, than you have only tow options:

- further reduce size of your tables
- use two (or more) pages for them

For both these solution, I believe, you not need our help :)